# How can I make the "edit" action the default action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a RESTful resource

```
map.resources :books
```

and I want to make the `edit` action the default one, in other words:

```
/books/1        # edit action
/books/1/show   # show action
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
map.connect "/books/:id", :controller => "books", :action => "edit"
```

Should do the trick.